# Cannot mount encrypted time machine drive after unmount

Tags: macos, hard-drive, time-machine, catalina, core-storage

I have an 3TB external HDD with 2 partitions, one of them is 1TB dedicated to time machine (encrypted).

It works perfectly, but whenever I unmount the partitions (by using right click, Eject via finder, which offers the option to "Eject All" partitions of this drive).

When I plug the drive back in, the non-encrypted non-time-machine partition mounts fine automatically, but not the (encrypted) time machine one.

Trying to mount via the Disk Utility app yield the following error:

> com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter error -119930868.)

Trying to mount via Terminal by running `$> diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume GUID` first to unlock the drive, then mounting that partition via `$> diskutil mount GUID` does not work either.

Sometimes `$> diskutil list` will just hand indefinitely, and when this happens even shutting down does not work (I guess macOS is waiting for something).

The only workaround I have is too reboot the mac; so that makes me think that it is not an issue with my drive.

Note: The disk is not plugged in directly, but through a thunberbolt3 dock (Caldigit TS3+).

Comment: Diagnostic question: If you plug the drive directly into into the computer, does the problem remain? If not, you may need to update the drivers on the dock; if so, then the dock is not the issue.

Comment: Thanks, @TedWrigley that was on my todo list, will try and keep you posted.

Comment: Diagnostic things you could check off:
- Connect the drive directly
- Do a pram and smc reset 
- Try a different Thunderbolt cable
- Try on a different mac, with and without the dock

Comment: I did manage to get it to work *once* by manually ejecting (via diskutil eject), but I was never able to replicate that.

Comment: When unlocking the volume via the terminal via unlockVolume, and then trying to remount it via mount I get this message (via diskutil activity):  >***DiskDescriptionChanged ('disk4', DAVolumeMountable = '0', DAVolumeKind = '<null>', DAVolumeName = '<null>', DAVolumeType = '<null>', DAVolumeUUID = '<null>') Time=20200111-17:24:41.4690
***DAIdle (no DADiskRef) Time=20200111-17:24:41.4690
Note that everything is "<null>".

Comment: So, the "normal situation", the drive connected, system boots, no problem... but then when you start to interact with the drive-state (unmount, eject), that is when problems occur?